# how to extract value of an input element in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please I want to extract the value of the input           form with id input-a but the program keeps writing c instead of the value entered by the user. Please help. This is the JavaScript code.

```
< body>
<script>
function tableCreate() {
var body = document.body,
tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.width = '100px';
tbl.style.border = '2px solid black';
  var n = 5
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();                                                      
    var td =tr.insertCell(0);
    var tf = tr.insertCell(0);
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = "input-a" + i;
    input.id = "input-a" + i;
    input.value = "";
    var clone = input.cloneNode();
    clone.name = "input-b" + i;
    clone.id = "input-b" + i;
    td.appendChild(clone);
    tf.appendChild(input);
    td.style.border = '2px solid black';
    tf.style.border = '2px solid black';
}
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.appendChild(tbl);
  body.appendChild(form);
  var submit = document.createElement("input");
  submit.type = "submit";
  form.appendChild(submit)
  Var c= document.getElementById("input-a1)
  document.write('c'). }
  tableCreate(); 
 </script>
 </body >
```

Comment: selection.value, selection being the input. So for example, document.getElementById('input-a1').value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Comment: you a missing a quotation mark here `Var c= document.getElementById("input-a1)` it should be `Var c= document.getElementById("input-a1")`
also remove quotation marks here `document.write('c')`
If it does not start working after you fixed the code let us know so we can help :)

Comment: Once you've done the above, to get the correct value, `document.write('c')` will output the character "c", as you say.  It should be `document.write(c)` (notice no quotes around the c)

Answer (score 1):

code is writing 'c' because you type

```
document.write('c')
```

if you want to have value of c you should type

```
document.write(c.value);
```

but to have it working you should set this value in function which handles forms submit not after generating form...because now value is empty string

here you have working example
https://jsfiddle.net/g8rschsu/

Comment: I tried it but when the page loads, the table shows followed by the string "undefined". Even after entering the numbers in input boxes and clicking submit. The page just simply reloads instead of showing the value of the input with id input-a1

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        function tableCreate() {
            var body = document.body;
            var tbl = document.createElement('table');
            tbl.style.width = '100px';
            tbl.style.border = '2px solid black';
            var n = 5;
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                var tr = tbl.insertRow();
                var td = tr.insertCell(0);
                var tf = tr.insertCell(0);
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.name = "input-a" + i;
                input.id = "input-a" + i;
                input.value = "test";
                var clone = input.cloneNode();
                clone.name = "input-b" + i;
                clone.id = "input-b" + i;
                td.appendChild(clone);
                tf.appendChild(input);
                td.style.border = '2px solid black';
                tf.style.border = '2px solid black';
            }
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.appendChild(tbl);
            body.appendChild(form);
            var submit = document.createElement("input");
            submit.type = "submit";
            form.appendChild(submit)
            var c = document.getElementById("input-a1").value;
            document.write(c);
        };
        tableCreate();
    };
 </script>
```

I saw you did document.write('c') with quotes,
this will write the string c and not the variable c.

Also you have to take the value of the input and not the input itself.

var c = document.getElementById("input-a1").value;

Comment: Can you send your script file, because I tried it and it worked

Comment: Also make check your developer tool, to see if the changes you made reflected here. Often the source file is not updated, in cause of the browser cach